# how to check consecutive objects are same using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var list = [
       {name :a,id:1,index:1},
       {name :a,id:1,index:2},
       {name :b,id:2,index:3},
       {name :c,id:3,index:4},
       {name :b,id:2,index:5},
];
```

i want to avoid the above situation , here object having  name = a

coming twice consecutively. But whereas object having name = b

is acceptable

> i expect some buil it funtion which will find these type of objects. just like isNaN

tried with plain javascript but need function in underscore.

## Downvoters pls comment before down voting :)

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: what do you mean by check? a boolean value or do you need a reordering of the array?

Comment: i expected some function which will take these array of objects as input and outputs if this array has consecutive object or not ? boolean value . no need of ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You coud use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the check. It stops the iteration if a result is `false`.

```js
var list = [{ name: 'a', id: 1, index: 1 }, { name: 'a', id: 1, index: 2 }, { name: 'b', id: 2, index: 3 }, { name: 'c', id: 3, index: 4 }, { name: 'b', id: 2, index: 5 }],
    notConsecutive = list.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return !i || aa[i - 1].name !== a.name;
    });

console.log(notConsecutive);
```